# BASH from a whois list to print multiple files for each whois

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I wrote in bash a simple script to whois multiple ip addresses I've in a huge list (list.txt) and the results of this search are written in a huge single files "results.txt".

My goal is to run the script but I need to write a single file for each ip address saved with the ip address i've searched.

I'm really stuck here, any help is appreciated.
Thanks

```
    #!/bin/bash
for domain in `cat iplist.txt`
do
   echo $domain
   `whois $domain >> results.txt`
done
```

Comment: Add semicolons after the `for` line, the `echo` line, and the `whois` line.  Remove the backquotes from the `whois` line.  Make sure you are not going to upset the owner of the whois server by batching requests!

Comment: Without the ` the script doesn't work

Comment: This works perfectly for me: `for domain in $(cat iplist.txt); do echo "${domain}"; whois ${domain} >> out.txt; done`.  A line of my `iplist.txt` file looks like `8.8.8.8`.  (And again, be careful about large numbers of requests.  You might be blocked.)

Comment: @Tony Semicolons are not needed at the end of lines (the newline itself does essentially the same thing), except for a few cases like the double-semicolon in a `case` statement. @Ebm_S3c the backticks around the `whois` command are telling bash to execute its output as a command (fortunately, its output is redirected to the file, so bash never actually sees it); this *cannot* be doing anything useful here.

Comment: @GordonDavisson what do you mean when you say "this cannot be doing anything useful here?"

Comment: I mean the backticks are useless. They tell bash to execute the command's output as a if it were a command itself, but since the actual output is redirected, it gets nothing... and hence executes nothing. If removing the backticks makes it fail, then something really *REALLY* weird is going on. (On the other hand, the backticks around `cat iplist.txt` are necessary, although it'd be better to use `$( )` instead and better still to [use a `while read` loop](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).)

Comment: @GordonDavisson I don't know why you say it executes nothing because it works perfectly this way but without backtcks it fails. Have you tried?

Comment: @Ebm_S3c It works exactly the same for me whether those backticks are there or removed. How does it fail when you remove them?